# after sending GET request only get status response, not response body

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am working on communication between API <-> webAPP via HttpClient.

This is my API controller:

```
        [HttpGet, Route("protocols")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetProtocols()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _repository.GetProtocols();
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // to do 

            return BadRequest(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

this is "fired" from website:

```
        var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/api/configuration/protocols");
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Content.ToString());
```

and this is result:
[image]

but this is result via swagger:
[image]

I dont know why i dont get result body in website, just status.

###UPDATE

This is my code:

```
        var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/api/configuration/protocols");
        var test = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Content.ToString());
```

and this is "test" result:

[image]

Comment: `Content` isn't a string, you will want to read the content, for instance: `await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: same result ://

Comment: Can you update the question with your new code? I'm not convinced you are doing it quite right. That should work.

Comment: idk why this wont work at first time. Now this works. Please make an answer i will mark as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content isn't just a string, you will want to read the content. If the payload contains JSON or other string data you can:

```
await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```